# How can I use async/await with a Promise subclass?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

I have a custom `Promise` class. How can I use it with `async/await`?

```
type Resolve<T> = (x: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void
type Reject     = (reason?: any) => void

class LoggingPromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
    constructor(f: (res: Resolve<T>, rej: Reject) => void) {
        super((resolve, reject) => f(
            (x) => {console.log(`I resolved to ${x}!`); resolve(x)}, 
            reject
        ))
    }
}

function inc(x: number): LoggingPromise<number> {
    return new LoggingPromise(resolve => resolve(x + 1))
}
```

I can `await` my custom promise just fine:

```
function logAnswer() {
    const answer = await inc(2)
    console.log(`I got answer ${answer}`)
}

>> logAnswer()
// I resolved to 3!
// I got answer 3!
```

But I can't return my custom promise from an `async` method:

```
async torgle(): LoggingPromise<number> {
    const answer = await inc(2)
    return LoggingPromise.resolve(answer * 5)
}
// ERROR: The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type. 
// Did you mean to write 'Promise<number>'?
```

If I `ts-ignore` this, it works fine*:

```
// @ts-ignore <-- can I do something about this?
async function torgle(x: number): LoggingPromise<number> {
    const answer = await inc(x)
    return LoggingPromise.resolve(answer * 5)
}

async function main() {
    const answer = await torgle(2)
    console.log(`I got answer ${answer}!`)
}

>> main()
// I resolved to 3!
// I resolved to 15!
// I got answer 15!
```

See [Typescript playground example](https://tsplay.dev/N5zp5m).

(*Well, kinda. I don't understand why it spawns `undefined` promises, but they don't seem to affect the final result.)

Is there some way I can convince Typescript to let me use the `async` keyword on a method returning my custom promise?

Comment: ***But I can't return my custom promise from an async method*** - I think this is how `async` methods are designed.  They always return a system promise, not yours.

Comment: Oh yeah jfriend00 is right. The returned value is *always* wrapped in `Promise`. You can't use an async function if you want to use your promise class.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use async/await with a Promise subclass?

You can't. You can `await` any thenable (object with a `.then()` method), including instances of your promise subclass. But an `async function` will always return a native `Promise`, never a subclass instance.

> Is there some way I can convince Typescript to let me use the async keyword on a method returning my custom promise?

No. What you have is not a method return a custom promise. This is not something that TypeScript can be "convinced" into allowing. It's a fundamental limitation being imposed by the JavaScript runtime.

> [If I ignore the error], it works fine

No, it doesn't. It's still the same as

```
async torgle(): Promise<number> {
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const answer = await inc(2)
    return LoggingPromise.resolve(answer * 5)
}
```

Remember that `async`/`await` is just syntactic sugar for

```
torgle(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Promise.resolve(inc(2)).then(answer => {
            resolve(LoggingPromise.resolve(answer * 5));
        });
    });
}
```

It won't make a difference that calling `LoggingPromise.resolve()` will log the result - the return value is still a native promise:

```
const promise = torgle();
console.log(promise instanceof LoggingPromise); // false
```

Comment: Ok, so `async` always wraps the result in a (native) `Promise`. Next question, then: how can I hijack the definition of `Promise` and replace it with my custom version? (I'm not sure I want to do that, but I'd like to know if it's possible.)

Comment: No, this is not possible. `async` functions use the builtin native promise construction, not the global `Promise`.